# Problems to accept an HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, php, html

I think my question isn't new, so sorry if this were already asked but I couldn't find something similar to my problem.
I want to send a XMLHttpRequest from an html file to an external php file. In this php file there is an HTTP_accept and this shall return an array with json_encode so I can load the array return to the html file.

I think my problem is in the `document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = event.target.response.date;` somehow the if statement from the `HTTP_Accept` is always false and therefore i can't access it.

My javascript file:

```
function loadTodo(){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = event.target.response.date;
});
xhr.responseType="json";
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/todo_js/read.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.send();
}
```

My php file:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] == 'application/json'):
foreach ($pdo->query($query) as $row) {

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['dotitle'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $status = $row['status'];
echo json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>
```

and my HTML file:

```
<button onClick="loadTodo()">ToDo laden</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById is looking for a html element. You have $data as a php variable. These things will not work together.

Also, as I learn I now have better results by designing test for each step of the process you’re coding. If you have a test for each block of code and only write one function per block, you can practice any unit testing paradigm. Thinking about troubleshooting as the process of designing test for each line of code helps me find the answer for my self 90% of the time.